# NgIf multiple template variables

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I found that

```
<div
  *ngIf="asyncCond$ | async as c1 && cond2"
></div>
```

Won't work.
Is there a way to define multiple conditions with multiple aliases in a one directive?

Like `asyncCond1$ | async as c1 && asyncCond2$ | async as c2` and so on. Adding `()` doesn't seem to make any impact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only declare a single `as` alias using a structural directive, but here is what I do.

You can use [combineLatest()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) to combine together multiple observables and create a state object that is used in the templates. You create a single object where the properties are a snapshot of the multiple observable values.

```js
   this.state$ = combineLatest(asyncCond1$, asyncCond2$, asyncCond3$).pipe(
      map(([asyncCond1, asyncCond2, asyncCond3]) => ({asyncCond1, asyncCond2, asyncCond3}))
   );
```

Now you can use the state object like this in the template.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="state$ | async as state">
    <div *ngIf="state.asyncCond1 && state.asyncCond2"></div>
    <div *ngIf="state.asyncCond3"></div>
    <div>
       {{state.asyncCond1 ? "Yes" : "No"}}
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

For more complex templates that use several observables it makes things a lot easier to work with.